# Get value of NOW() in MySQLi PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Assume that your webserver is detached from your database server. Their clocks might not be properly synchronized (down to milliseconds etc.).

You perform an insert such as `"INSERT INTO sometable (VALUE,VALUE2,DATETIME) VALUES ("something","something else",NOW());"`

Is there any way to get the timestamp generated by MySQL back into PHP? In the same fashion as when using `$sqlObject->insert_id` to get the AUTO_INCREMENT value of the last inserted row.

Edit:
I realize I could just use the `insert_id` and run a `SELECT` to get the timestamp, but this would require that I run another statement. I am wondering if it is possible in a single statement.

Comment: Not entirely sure how getting the value back to PHP is going to help anything. You'd be able to work out the difference, but then what? Just get both machines synced up to an NTP server.

Comment: You can write stored procedure which inserts data into table and then returns last record inserted.

Comment: @JonStirling The timestamp functions as a "passcode" to be able to edit the row. If you have the correct timestamp it means nobody else altered the row after you opened it (in the application). So if I cannot return the exact timestamp the client will not be able to edit the row again until it's been refreshed manually (reloading all timestamps in an entirely different function).

Comment: @Code-Monk In my particular case the statement is actually an UPDATE, and it runs on AWS RDS which does not allow stored procedures that alter SQL. I used INSERT in the question to simplify the problem.

Comment: If you're determined to do it this way, instead of getting mysql to generate the value, why not get PHP to do it and pass the value in? Then you know exactly what the datetime entered is and don't need anything back from the INSERT? (where value = the datetime).

Comment: I could do that, yes. I also will if it's not possible the other way around :)

Comment: As mentioned by @RonaldSwets I believe the only way with mysql is to retrieve the row since SPs aren't available and it doesn't implement anything like PostgreSQL's RETURNING afaik.

Comment: I think I'll just restructure a bit and use PHP to generate the timestamp.

Comment: Note that `NOW()` has a resolution of 1 second, so on a reasonably busy server, your assumption "two edits at the same second cannot happen" is not guaranteed.

Comment: I have logic in place that prevents this from being an issue :)

Comment: @RyanVincent - stored procedures that alter SQL are not allowed on Amazon RDS. I think it has something to do with their multi AZ deployment technology

Comment: This good question is still unanswered after 3+ years. If user is unable to directly access the exact same value generated by NOW() when the column is updated then at least user should be able to directly invoke NOW().

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the direct value but you can do it via 2 ways.

1) Make a select query like select now() as cur_time. and take its value and use in the 2nd query. [ Its possible that you might get different time for this solution, SO i will suggest not to go with this solution and better you go with option 2. ]

2) After inserting the data get its ID and and make a query and get the inserted date time.

If your PHP and MYSQL server date time are same then you may use php's date function to get the current date / time .

Comment: Your first suggestion **might** give two different results in edge cases, as the timestamp may increment from one NOW() to the next.

Comment: Yes right and that is why i am also don't suggest it.  Let me update my answer and add a RED alert.